# python: directory with values other then occurrence of keys

Tags: python, directory, zip, key

How can I make a directory have values count from a list that is associated with the Keys, opposed to the occurrences of a particular Key.

**EXAMPLE:** I have two lists, One is of strings, and one is of a values for each string. 
say:

```
strings = ['me', 'you', 'me', 'her','her']
values = [1,20,6,35,5]
```

and I want:

```
directory = {'me':7, 'you':20, 'her':40}
```

This is how I have been making directories:

```
d = {}
for i in list:
    if i in d:
        d[i] = d[i]+1
    else:
        d[i] = 1
valueKeys = zip(d.values(),d.keys())
value = d.values()
keys = d.keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for x, y in zip(strings, values):
...     d[x] += y
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'you': 20, 'her': 40, 'me': 7})
```

The resulted `defaultdict` object can act as plain `dict`:

```
for key in d:
    print(key, d[key])
```

Output:

```
me 7
her 40
you 20
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this has the side-effect that if you try to access `d[key]`, where `key` is some key that isn't explicitly in `d`, you'll get `0`. The above `d`, for instance, would give `print d['nobody'] -> 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
    #x=numbers
    #list = names
    d = {}
    for i in list:
        if i in d:
            d[i] = d[i]+x[list.index(i)]
        else:
            d[i] = x[list.index(i)]
    valueKeys = zip(d.values(),d.keys())
    value = d.values()
    keys = d.keys()
```

This was how I solved it